# CONEXIONES UDP CLIENTE-SERVIDOR

Tags: java, socket

**Necesito que este programa permita que el cliente pueda leer los mensajes que le envía el servidor, pero no se como.
En si el programa puede hacer que el cliente envíe mensajes al servidor y este lo reciba, pero cuando quiero que el servidor envíe un mensaje al cliente y este lo  lea no me permite.

**ESTE ES EL CODIGO DEL CLIENTE**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import java.net.*;

import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class cliente {
        public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            Scanner entrada= new Scanner(System.in);
            String mens =  " " ;
            String nombreser="DESKTOP-PRKKNMM";
            do {
                System.out.println("Cliente - Ingrese un mensaje: ");
                mens = entrada.nextLine();
                DatagramSocket socketUDP = new DatagramSocket();
                byte[] mensaje = mens.getBytes();
                InetAddress hostServidor = InetAddress.getByName(nombreser);
                int puertoServidor = 6789;
                DatagramPacket peticion = new DatagramPacket(mensaje, mens.length(), hostServidor, puertoServidor);
                socketUDP.send(peticion);
                byte[] bufer = new byte[1000];
                DatagramPacket respuesta = new DatagramPacket(bufer, bufer.length);
                socketUDP.receive(respuesta);//recibe respuesta
                System.out.println("Respuesta: " + new String(respuesta.getData()));
                socketUDP.close();
            }while(!mens.equals("Adios"));
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            System.out.println("Socket: " + e.getMessage());
        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.print("IO: " +e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Y ESTE ES EL CODIGO DEL SERVIDOR**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import java.io.PrintWriter;

import java.net.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

    
    public class servidor{
        public static void main (String args []) {
            try{
                Scanner entrada= new Scanner(System.in);
                String resp =  " " ;
                DatagramSocket socketUDP= new DatagramSocket(6789);
                byte[] bufer= new byte[1000];
                while (true){
                    DatagramPacket peticion= new DatagramPacket(bufer, bufer.length);
                    socketUDP.receive(peticion);
                    System.out.println("Datagrama recibido del host: " +peticion.getAddress());
                    System.out.println("desde el puerto remoto: " +peticion.getPort());
                    DatagramPacket respuesta = new DatagramPacket(peticion.getData(),peticion.getLength(),peticion.getAddress(), peticion.getPort());
                    socketUDP.send(respuesta);
                    System.out.println("Respuesta: " + new String(respuesta.getData()));
                    //pedir que ingrese mensaje
                    System.out.println("Servidor - Ingresa un mensaje ");
                    resp = entrada.nextLine();
                    byte[] responder = resp.getBytes();
                }
            }catch (SocketException e){
                System.out.println("Socket: " +e.getMessage());
            }catch (IOException e){
                System.out.println("IOException: "+e.getMessage());
            }
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Esto es Java, no JavaScript. Por favor haz clic en [edit] y cambia las etiquetas.

Comment: Gracias MAURICIO